# Why does Sequelize say the table doesn't existed if I've already defined the model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using a SQLite3 database with [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org) as an ORM. I have one model/table in the database named "cities" which I created before I set up `sequelize-cli` so there's no migration file that creates the table. I'm trying to add 4 new attributes/columns to the model/table. I followed the official guide and created a project with `npx sequelize-cli init`, then created a migration with `npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name summer-update-2023`. After writing the file, I tried to run the migration with `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`. I got the following error:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 17.3.0, CLI: 6.6.1, ORM: 6.31.1]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20230811163435-summer-update-2023: migrating =======

ERROR: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: cities
```

I'm not sure why I received this error since I had defined the model and synced the database months ago. Here is my code: 
**migrations/20230811163435-summer-update-2023.js:**

```js
'use strict';

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.addColumn('cities', 'safety', {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 50,
      }),
      queryInterface.addColumn('cities', 'policeLevel', {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
      }),
      queryInterface.addColumn('cities', 'fireLevel', {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
      }),
      queryInterface.addColumn('cities', 'hospitalsBuilt', {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
      }),
    ]);
  },

  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.removeColumn('cities', 'safety'),
      queryInterface.removeColumn('cities', 'policeLevel'),
      queryInterface.removeColumn('cities', 'fireLevel'),
      queryInterface.removeColumn('cities', 'hospitalsBuilt'),
    ]);
  },
};
```

**models/cities.js:** (the comments are for personal reference)

```js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { db } = require('../database.js');

const Cities = db.define('cities', {
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    happiness: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 1,
    },
    population: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 100,
    },
    balance: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 500,
    },
    resources: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 500,
    },
/*  safety: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 50,
    }
*/
    crowdedness: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
    },
    traffic: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 5,
    },
    pollution: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
    },
    residentialLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 1,
        validate: { max: 15 },
    },
    commercialLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 1,
        validate: { max: 15 },
    },
    industrialLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 1,
        validate: { max: 15 },
    },
    roadLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 1,
        validate: { max: 10 },
    },
    busLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
    },
    parkLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
    },
/*  policeLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
    },
    fireLevel: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 10 },
    },
*/
    plazasBuilt: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 5 },
    },
    busStationsBuilt: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 5 },
    },
/*  hospitalsBuilt: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: { max: 5 },
    },
*/
});

module.exports = { Cities };
```

**db-init.js:** (ran before migration and everytime bot starts)

```js
const { db } = require('./database.js');
require('./models/cities.js');

const force = process.argv.includes('--force') || process.argv.includes('-f');

db.sync({ force }).then(async () => {
    console.log('Database synced.');

    db.close();
}).catch(console.error);
```

(database.js defines the database) 
**config/config.js:**

```json
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "sqlite"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "sqlite"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "sqlite"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the database if the "cities" table really exists? Sometimes the case sensitiveness matters.

Comment: I ran the bot and used the command to show me my city and it showed it. When I defined the model I used lowercase.

Comment: Can't you look at the database yourself? Btw. I use `Modelname.tableName` instead of typing out blindly table names. Try that. I don't know what that is for you; `City.tableName` maybe

Comment: Wait I just checked via `db.isDefined` and it's not defined. But the bot still works fine...

Comment: If you've managed to resolve this you can send your findings.